# Why won't Access allow me to access its tables?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

In trying to figure out why I'm getting "internal server error 500" when I try to run a query against some MS Access tables from my Web API app, I opened Access and its jump-through-these-hoops query functionality (there's probably an easier way, but the only way I've found to run a query is to select Create > Query Design > Close the dialog > right-click on the surface of the query window and select SQL View > Run button) to try to verify the query I'm using will compile and return results in Access itself.

However, when I try to do that, I get:

> The table 'td_duckbill_accounts' is already opened exclusively by another user, or it is already open through the user interface and cannot be manipulated programmatically.

Both the VS 2013 Web API app and the VS 2008 client that calls it do not have their projects running, so neither should have this table open. So how do I close the table so that I can run the query in Access?

Comment: Side note: Microsoft Access is probably the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @LarsTech: No doubt, but that decision is not mine; this is a legacy app that does, for better or WORSE, use Access as well as a lot of other "classic" approaches/tools/methodologies/mindsets.

Comment: @Tim: Code? Why? It's just a query/SQL statement. The Web API code works - it works with a different (test) query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

back up everything, delete the lock files associated with the db.  if that dont work, maybe try a compact and repair.  if all else fails, try contacting Gyro Gearloose